# How to hide a form after submit? (Java, Jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I'm new here. I need to know more about jsp page. I'd like to hide the form after button "submit"
is pressed, in this Jsp page, in order to view the result of filling
the form.
This page, as written, when I press "crea contatto" it shows me both the form and the result of filling out the form. How can i see
only the result?

Thanks a lot!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Aggiunto nuovo contatto</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- header -->
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />



    <h1>Aggiungi un nuovo contatto</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="AggiungiPersona.do">


        Id: <input type="number" size="40 maxlength=40" name="id" /><br />
        Nome: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="nome" /><br />
        Cognome: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="cognome" /><br />
        Anni: <input type="number" size="40 maxlength=40" name="anni" /><br />
        Sesso: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="sesso" /><br />
        Indirizzo: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="indirizzo" /><br />
        Numero di telefono: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40"
            name="numTel" /><br /> Email: <input type="text"
            size="40 maxlength=40" name="email" /><br /> <br> <input
            type="submit" value="crea contatto">


    </form>



    <c:choose>






        <c:when test="${error==true}">
            <h1>Errore</h1>
            <p>Attenzione! Inserire un'età compresa tra 0 e 100.</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="./aggiungiPersona.html">Torna al form</a>
            <br>
        </c:when>

        <c:when test="${error2==true}">
            <h1>Errore</h1>
            <p>Attenzione! L'id che si sta cercando di inserire è già
                presente in database. Scegliere un id diverso.</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="./aggiungiPersona.html">Torna al form</a>
            <br>
        </c:when>

        <c:when test="${error3==true}">
            <h1>Errore</h1>
            <p>Attenzione! Il valore associato a "sesso" può essere solo "m",
                "M", "f", "F".</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="./aggiungiPersona.html">Torna al form</a>
            <br>
        </c:when>


        <c:when test="${error4==true}">
            <h1>Errore</h1>
            <p>Attenzione! Il numero di telefono può contenere solo numeri.</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="./aggiungiPersona.html">Torna al form</a>
            <br>
        </c:when>

        <c:when test="${error5==true}">
            <h1>Errore</h1>
            <p>Attenzione! L'email deve contenre il simbolo '@'.</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="./aggiungiPersona.html">Torna al form</a>
            <br>
        </c:when>

        <c:when test="${successo==true}">
            <h1>Aggiunto nuovo contatto!</h1>

            <p>
                Id:
                <% String id = request.getParameter("id"); out.print(id); %>
                <br /> Nome:
                <% String nome = request.getParameter("nome"); out.print(nome); %>
                <br /> Cognome:
                <% String cognome = request.getParameter("cognome"); out.print(cognome); %>
                <br /> Età:
                <% String anni = request.getParameter("anni"); out.print(anni); %>
                <br /> Sesso:
                <% String sesso = request.getParameter("sesso"); out.print(sesso); %>
                <br /> Indirizzo:
                <% String indirizzo = request.getParameter("indirizzo"); out.print(indirizzo); %>
                <br /> Numero di telefono:
                <% String numTel = request.getParameter("numTel"); out.print(numTel); %>
                <br /> Email:
                <% String email= request.getParameter("email"); out.print(email); %>
                <br />
            </p>




        </c:when>



        <c:otherwise>

            <br>
            <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a>
            <br>

        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can surround your `<form></form>` tag around some condition i.e : `<% if(request.getParameter("id") == null) { %> //Yourform <% } %>` .

Comment: I don't know... beacause i need to display this form when the Jsp page appears for the first time, but when i click submit, I need the form to disappear.
other suggestions?

Comment: Hi when you load your page for the first time value of `id` will be `null` so that should work,, your form will be shown.. after submitting your `form` your `id` will have some value so form will not shown.. because of `null` conditon.Also , here `id` is `name="id"`  .

Comment: And i am thinking you are submitting your form on same page ?

Comment: i'm saving data on database and the result is printed on the same jsp. Thanks

Comment: where is db code on same page ? does `out.print(id);` gets printed ? after submit?

Comment: the db code is in an other class because i'm trying to respect the MVC model. And yes, out.print(id); gets printed on jsp page!

Comment: Then you can store value in session which will help you to identify to view form or not..So, onload of jsp value in session will be null and  in your backend code you can assign some value to it. Then you use my above comment just replace request.getParameter..to request.getAttribute..and do same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<c:if>` tests to see whether or not you want it to be hidden or not.

For example:

```
<c:if test="${id} ne null">
    <form>
    </form>
</c:if>
```

Comment: I don't know... beacause i need to display this form when the Jsp page appears for the first time, but when i click submit, I need the form to disappear. 
other suggestions?

Comment: @MatteoBattilani Just set `id` to null when you want the form to disappear.